# Prove using mean value theorem that, $2x \le \frac{\log(1+x)}{1-x} \le\frac{2x}{1-x^2}$ where $0<x<1$

Tags: calculus

I tried using Lagrange and Cauchy mean value theorem. I am not able to find which function to use other than log.

Comment: Please give the details of what you tried. Google MathJax tutorials.

Comment: Wouldn't  the function be $\;\log\Bigl(\dfrac{1+x}{1-x} \Bigr)$?

Comment: The inequality does not hold for all $x$ (e.g. $x=0$)

Answer (score 1):

This is false. If it were true, we would have

$$2x-2x^2 \le \ln (1+x) \le x,\,\, 0<x<1.$$

I have used the well known inequality $\ln(1+x) <x$ for $x>0.$ This implies $1\le 2x$ as $x\to 0^+,$ contradiction.